# Where is the logout button on stack overflow?

Tags: support, logout

Where is the logout button? I can't find it anywhere! I have looked everywhere for a button but to no luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is here - on right side of the included picture (near "help" and "chat")

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's at the top of the list of all StackExchange sites, available under the hamburger button.

Answer (score 1):

top right corner chat bubble icon thing > log out